# Calculate the optimal ratio AX/AB

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram. By a dot $ x$ on the $\overline {AB}$ with $\overline {AX} <\overline{XB}$, draw a line parallel to $\overline{BC}$. This line, along with the diagonals and sides of the parallelogram, will determine $3$ quads. Knowing that the sum of the areas of these quads is as large as possible, calculate the ratio $\frac{\overline{AX}} {\overline{AB}}$

I tried to explain the reasons between perimeters and harmonic beams, but it didn't work on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let the area of ABCD be 1 and, with the ratios of the similar triangles, calculate the areas of the triangle $a$, $b$ and $c$ as,

$$A_a = A_b= \frac{AX^2}{AB^2} A_{ACB}= \frac12 r^2$$

$$A_c = \frac{(\frac{AB}{2}-AX)^2}{(\frac{AB}{2})^2}A_{ADO} = \frac14 (1-2r)^2$$

where $r=\frac{AX}{AB}$, $A_{ACB}=\frac12$ and $A_{ADO} = \frac14$. The sum of $a$, $b$ and $c$ is then,

$$A(r) = r^2+\frac14(1-2r)^2$$

Take the derivative of $A(r)$ with respect to $r$ and set it to zero to minimize $A$, hence maximizing the sum of the three quads. We obtain the ratio,

$$r=\frac{AX}{AB}=\frac14$$

Comment: Very good! Thanks

Comment: @EsposaDoYoongi - Tkx. you are welcome.